# Comma or ampersand with multiple bounded types?

Tags: java, types

In Java, are commas and ampersands both valid when declaring a multiply bounded type?

```
class MyClass <T extends OtherInterface, SomeInterface>

class MyOtherClass <T extends OtherInterface & SomeInterface>
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

As others have pointed out, this:

```
class MyOtherClass <T extends OtherInterface & SomeInterface>
```

defines a multiply bounded type parameter.  If you use `MyOtherClass`, you must give it a type that implements both `OtherInterface` and `SomeInterface`.

However, this does *not* define a multiply bounded type parameter:

```
class MyClass <T extends OtherInterface, SomeInterface>
```

It defines a generic with two type parameters.  The first one must implement `OtherInterface`.  The second one can be anything.  It's just the same as

```
class MyClass <T extends OtherInterface, U>
```

except that you named it `SomeInterface` instead of `U`.  (The convention is that type parameters are normally single upper-case letters, or sometimes an upper-case letter and a digit or a short upper-case identifier.  But the compiler doesn't care.  It won't look at the form of the identifier to figure out that you really meant it as an interface.)

Answer (score 6):

Multiple Bounds are possible with `<T extends B1 & B2 & B3>` where B2 and B3 should be interface. B1 can be simple class or interface

Answer (score 3):

Commas and ampersand in the type bound definition mean different things.

The ampersand means that your type parameter is a subtype of all type parameter bounds joined by the '&'; as you might expect, the list of type parameter bounds must respect Java's multiple inheritance rules - i.e., at the most one class, multiple interfaces allowed.

The comma is a delimiter for the type bounds captured - so in your example, it means that you have two separate type arguments - T extends OtherInterface, and SomeInterface, so you'd have to use it like:

```
new MyClass<OtherInterfaceSubtype, SomeInterfaceSubType>();
```

I'm guessing this is not what you want.

Comment: Note that in the actual example given, `class MyClass <T extends OtherInterface, SomeInterface>`, the OP has defined two generic parameters. The first is called `T` and is bound by `OtherInterface`, and the second is (confusingly) called `SomeInterface` and is unbounded (so `SomeInterface` could actually be any class!)

Answer (score 2):

*found this rules:*

**Multiple Bounds**

The preceding example illustrates the use of a type parameter with a single bound, but a type parameter can have multiple bounds:

A type variable with multiple bounds is a subtype of all the types listed in the bound. If one of the bounds is a class, it must be specified first. For example:

```
Class A { /* ... */ }
interface B { /* ... */ }
interface C { /* ... */ }

class D <T extends A & B & C> { /* ... */ }
```

If bound A is not specified first, you get a compile-time error:

```
class D <T extends B & A & C> { /* ... */ }  // compile-time error
```