# Why won't this method with circular generics in its signature compile?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, corretto

I've made the following method that uses circular generic types in its signature.

```
private <U extends NameTranslation<T> & Autocompletable, T extends Polyonymous<U>> U createNameTranslationInstance(T parent, Language targetLanguage,
                                                                                            String translatedName, String translatedAutoSuggestionText) {
    if (parent instanceof Organism organism) {
        return (U) new OrganismCommonNameTranslation(organism, targetLanguage, translatedName, gardenerPlanet,
                translatedAutoSuggestionText, SubmissionStatus.APPROVED);
    } else if (parent instanceof LifeStage lifeStage) {
        return (U) new LifeStageCommonNameTranslation(lifeStage, targetLanguage, translatedName, gardenerPlanet,
                translatedAutoSuggestionText, SubmissionStatus.APPROVED);
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported parent type: " + parent.getClass().getName());
}
```

This method returns an object of type `U` which extends a NameTranslation abstract class with generic type `T` and also implements the interface `Autocompletable`. Generic type `T` is of a type that extends interface `Polyonymous` with a generic type `U`.

When I try to compile this it will throw a couple of java compiler errors for this method.

```
java: incompatible types: T cannot be converted to POJOs.TaxonomicPojos.Organism
java: incompatible types: POJOs.TaxonomicPojos.categorytranslations.OrganismCommonNameTranslation cannot be converted to U
java: incompatible types: T cannot be converted to POJOs.TaxonomicPojos.LifeStage
java: incompatible types: POJOs.TaxonomicPojos.categorytranslations.LifeStageCommonNameTranslation cannot be converted to U
```

But both `Organism` and `LifeStage` extend `Polyonymous<>` and the associated CommonNameTranslation classes each extend NameTranslation and implement `AutoCompletable`.

When I remove `extends Polyonymous<U>` and thereby removing the circular reference everything compiles again. I've googled to see if circular generic dependencies aren't allowed in Java. But according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2656027/6351733) circular generics are perfectly allowable.

It gets even weirder when I remove `& Autocompletable` from the method signature instead of the `extends Polyonymous` part. Now this method causes an internal java compiler error instead.

```
java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error
```

This type of error can occur due to a variety of reasons, including incorrect syntax in the code, incorrect usage of Java language constructs, memory or disk space issues, or bugs in the Java compiler itself [(source)](https://medium.com/@teamcode20233/troubleshooting-internal-java-compiler-error-during-compilation-e054b98184f).

So what is it about this generic signature that causes compile issues?

Here are all the class definitions

```
    public class Organism implements Polyonymous<OrganismCommonNameTranslation>{
    
    }
    
    public class LifeStage implements Polyonymous<LifeStageCommonNameTranslation>{
    
    }
    
    public class OrganismCommonNameTranslation extends NameTranslation<Organism> implements Autocompletable {
    
    }
    
    public class LifeStageCommonNameTranslation extends NameTranslation<LifeStage> implements Autocompletable {
    
    }

public abstract class NameTranslation<T>{}

    public interface Polyonymous<T>{}
    
    public interface Autcompletable{}
```

EDIT: Here's my java version info

```
openjdk 20.0.2.1 2023-08-22
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-20.0.2.10.1 (build 20.0.2.1+10-FR)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-20.0.2.10.1 (build 20.0.2.1+10-FR, mixed mode, sharing)
```

EDIT 07/12/2023

The internal java error seems to be caused by the explicit cast to (U) in combination with circular generic references.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870398/comma-or-ampersand-with-multiple-bounded-types I knew it can have multiple interfaces but...    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870398/comma-or-ampersand-with-multiple-bounded-types

Comment: T means a "class" must be filled in for T of the object (not a primitive) .   "U" means the type checked hierarchy Upper-Bound must not be a class extending higher than the class as "U extends SomeClass"    -   just happened on a good tut pinch  https://java-programming.mooc.fi/part-12/1-type-parameters       and lower bounded wildcard is <? super A>   upper bounded wildcard is <? extends A>     https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is ok theoretically, but it seem like compiler is not smart enough.

I modified your code a little to fool compiler and it run well. Here is the code:

```
private <U extends NameTranslation<T> & Autocompletable, T extends Polyonymous<U>> U createNameTranslationInstance(T parent, Language targetLanguage,
                                                                                            String translatedName, String translatedAutoSuggestionText) {
    if ((Object) parent instanceof Organism organism) {
        return (U) (Object) new OrganismCommonNameTranslation(organism, targetLanguage, translatedName, gardenerPlanet,
                translatedAutoSuggestionText, SubmissionStatus.APPROVED);
    } else if ((Object) parent instanceof LifeStage lifeStage) {
        return (U) (Object) new LifeStageCommonNameTranslation(lifeStage, targetLanguage, translatedName, gardenerPlanet,
                translatedAutoSuggestionText, SubmissionStatus.APPROVED);
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported parent type: " + parent.getClass().getName());
}
```

I found that the compiler errors occur in these two part:

1. Use `instance of` to judge a generic variable is specific type
2. Cast a instance of a specific type to generic type

I think it may be better if you remove `extends NameTranslation<T> & Autocompletable` in your code, because they seem useless.

I still don't know the exact reason why the compiler throw those errors. But hope my answer could help you a little.

Comment: No the `extends NameTranslation<T> & Autocompletable` is not useless. This method is called by another method that expects <U extends NameTranslation<T> & Autocompletable>. NameTranslation and Autocompletable also define abstract methods. I just didn't include those in my post because they are irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Also, the casting of parent to (Object) and NameTranslation to (Object) and then to (U) right afterwards makes no sense whatsoever. If I wanted to use Object type i wouldn't have used generics in the first place.

Comment: 2. Casting parent to object is for using `instance of`, or compiler throw an error. While program running in JVM, generic type will be erased anyway. Yes, it is not the best way, but it works.

Comment: 1. if you hope the return of your method can be assigned to NameTranslation or Autocompletable, it's better to use `super` instead of `extends`. I mistakenly thought you hope to use the method like this: ```OrganismCommonNameTranslation translation1 = new Xxx().createNameTranslationInstance(new Organism(), ...);
        LifeStageCommonNameTranslation translation2 = new Xxx().createNameTranslationInstance(new LifeStage(), ...);```

Comment: You can't use `super` together with a generic type. super only works with a wildcard type. For example: `List<? super Integer> list`